# Wordpress thumbnail size change with a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm inserting images like this for a list of posts in wordpress:

```
<div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I want that if  has a class 'full' it inserts 'large' size post thumbnail instead of 'medium', like this:

```
<div class="full">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

... and for 'half', 'custom_medium_large':

```
<div class="half">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('custom_medium_large'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Both .half and .large classes are applied via jQuery:

```
$(".home .grid div:first").addClass("full");
$('.home div:not(:first-child):nth-child(8n+2), .home div:not(:first-child):nth-child(8n+3)').addClass('half');
```

Any idea how do I make sure that  container with .half or .full classes have corresponding image sizes than the default 'medium'?

Comment: it seems like only first one get full class and rest all are getting half class? Am I right?

Comment: Close enough. Most are without any class. There's only one instance of .full in the list and then several of .half which is applied after every few containers.

Comment: You have to manage it via PHP code then. through jquery no possible

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to include image tags for each size, and toggle the display of the image you want based on the absence/presence of the CSS class. This may require some custom coding of the image tags, so that only the image you need is loaded, and not costing the user bandwidth.

Untested code, but should get you close:

```php
$images = get_the_post_thumbnail( ‘medium’ );
$images .= get_the_post_thumbnail( ‘large’ );
$images .= get_the_post_thumbnail( ‘custom_medium_large’ );

printf(
    ‘<div class=“container-image”><a href=“%s$1” alt=“%s$2”>%s$3</a></div>’,
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( the_title_attribute( array( ‘echo’ => false ) ) ),
    $images
);
```

```css
div.container-image img:not( .size-medium ),
div.container-image.full img:not( .size-large ),
div.container-image.half img:not( .size-custom_medium_large ) {
    display: none;
}
```

You could also use jQuery to insert the image, with the URLs provided in a JSON object. That’s probably the better, more semantically correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme's functions.php file and Add the following code snippet to define a new thumbnail size:

```
function custom_thumbnail_size() {
    add_image_size( 'custom-thumbnail', 300, 200, true ); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_thumbnail_size' );
```

To display the custom thumbnail size in a template, you can use the

```
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <div class="custom-thumbnail-class">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-thumbnail' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to apply a CSS class to the thumbnail itself, you can do so in your theme's CSS file.

```
.custom-thumbnail-class img {
    /* CSS styles for the custom thumbnail */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Additional styles... */
}
```